# How to solve the Problem when we compile the deploy.js file in Ethereum Contract it give the node version error

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

Error: The module '/home/abdul/Documents/lottery/node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

```
 at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1206:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abdul/Documents/lottery/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
```

Comment: It appears node was upgraded between the initial installation and when running the scripts. Try reinstalling depedencies after clearing node_modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Please uninstall your node.js.
>   and install stable version of node.js